# Using gson, how to exclude a numeric type (double, integer) with default value from serialization?

Tags: serialization, gson

I am using gson for serialization and running into a problem. In the class "Person" I defined, there is a field "age", whose type is "int". This field is defaulted to 0 unless it is reset later. In serializing an object of Person, I want to exclude the field "age" if it is value is still 0. Can anybody tell me how to do that using gson?

Thanks,

Jianguo

Answer (score 4):

- [gson custom serialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)
- [excluding fields](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-User-Defined-Exclusion-Strategies)