# how to config gson to exclude 0 integer values

Tags: java, android

I've a Java class with lot of integer fields and when I want to serialize them to json string due to some of them could have no value, hence after serializing all integers get zero as values ! I want to config gson not to serialize them if they do not have any values.

for example I have this class :

```
class Example {
   String title = "something";
   int id = 22;
   int userId;
}
```

by default gson gives me this result :

```
{
   "title" : "something",
   "id" : 22,
   "userId" : 0
}
```

but i don't want the userId to be serialized when its value is 0. so the json should be:

```
{
   "title" : "something",
   "id" : 22
}
```

for objects by default gson doesn't serialize null objects is there a way to config gson not to serialize 0 numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using gson, how to exclude a numeric type (double, integer) with default value from serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316787/using-gson-how-to-exclude-a-numeric-type-double-integer-with-default-value-f)

Answer (score 34):

We have to just use class `Integer` ([Integer javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)).

```
class Example {
   String title = "something";
   Integer id = 22;
   Integer userId;
}
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what the question asked for. In this example, you've swapped 0 for null, and are taking advantage of GSON's "don't serialize nulls" feature.

Answer (score 9):

Create this JSON type adapter. It can be used where ever you want to ignore writing zero values. It can also be adapted to Long, Double and other numeric types. You can also change it to ignore writing a value other than zero.

Yes I know Autoboxing and Unboxing is implicitly used but you can't specify a primitive type for the generic type.

```
public class IntIgnoreZeroAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Integer> {
    private static Integer INT_ZERO = Integer.valueOf(0);

    @Override
    public Integer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if (in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
            in.nextNull();
            return 0;
        }

        return in.nextInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Integer data) throws IOException {
        if (data == null || data.equals(INT_ZERO)) {
            out.nullValue();
            return;
        }

        out.value(data.intValue());
    }
}
```

Change your class to specify the IntIgnoreZeroAdapter for the int members.

```
class Example {
   String title = "something";

   @JsonAdapter(IntIgnoreZeroAdapter.class)
   int id = 22;

   @JsonAdapter(IntIgnoreZeroAdapter.class)
   int userId;
}
```

Comment: if want to double value ignore?

Comment: Far more flexible and easier to implement than writing TypeAdapters for entire object classes.

Comment: If you don't want to use the annotation, it works registering the type adapter to the GsonBuilder: `builder.registerTypeAdapter(Integer.class, new IntAdapter());`

Answer (score 7):

You can write a custom `TypeAdapter`.

```
public class ExampleTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Example> {

    @Override
    public Example read(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        final Example example = new Example();

        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String name = in.nextName();
            if ("title".equals(name)) {
                example.title = in.nextString();
            } else if ("id".equals(name)) {
                example.id = in.nextInt();
            } else if ("userId".equals(name)) {
                example.userId = in.nextInt();
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        return example;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter out, Example example)
            throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("title").value(example.title);

        if(example.id != 0) {
            out.name("id").value(example.id);
        }

        if(example.userId != 0) {
            out.name("userId").value(example.userId);
        }

        out.endObject();
    }
}
```

Try it with code below:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Example.class, new ExampleTypeAdapter());
gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();

Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

Example example = new Example();
example.title = "mytitle";
example.id = 1234;
example.userId = 0;

final String json = gson.toJson(example);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output will be:

```
 {
   "title": "my title",
   "id": 1234
 }
```

**Note:** Important part is at `write` method of our custom `TypeAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to config gson not to serialize them if they do not have any values.

This sentence leads me to believe you misunderstand how variables and values work in Java. Note that all variables in Java have a value even if you don't explicitly assign one to them. If you declare an `int` and do not assign it a value, a default value of `0` will be assigned for you. So this:

```
int userId;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int userId = 0;
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Although Nitin Gawande's answer is not correct per se, I would still recommend it since I assume that's probably what you want. A `null` value for an `Integer` is a more reliable representation of a value that was never assigned than a zero value for an `int` (usually). And it allows you to make use of GSON's handy "don't serialize nulls" feature.

Comment: this was so long ago I don't remember what I ended up using, but the gist of it was that I didn't want ints with value of 0 to be serialized